# expanding_corr function in pandas gives NaN

Tags: python, pandas

The data file is [here](https://gist.github.com/kindlychung/681cf91a139bf9add5e9).

I am just trying to calculate the pairwise correlations between columns of two data frame:

```
In [7]: import os

In [8]: import pandas as pd

In [9]: import numpy as np

In [10]: from pandas import Series, DataFrame

In [12]: blog_dat = pd.read_table("blogdata.txt", index_col="Blog")

In [13]: blog_dat = blog_dat.astype(float)

In [14]: all(blog_dat.notnull())
Out[14]: True

In [15]: x = DataFrame(np.random.randn(99*4).reshape((99, 4)))

In [16]: pd.expanding_corr(blog_dat.iloc[:, :4], blog_dat.iloc[:, :4], pairwise=True)[-1, :, :]
Out[16]:
          china      kids     music     yahoo
china  1.000000  0.053069  0.026599  0.246957
kids   0.053069  1.000000  0.409978  0.094636
music  0.026599  0.409978  1.000000  0.055923
yahoo  0.246957  0.094636  0.055923  1.000000

In [17]: pd.expanding_corr(blog_dat.iloc[:, :4], x, pairwise=True)[-1, :, :]
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py:1240: RuntimeWarning: unorderable types: str() < int(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  "incomparable objects" % e, RuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py:1240: RuntimeWarning: unorderable types: int() < str(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  "incomparable objects" % e, RuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py:1254: RuntimeWarning: unorderable types: str() > int(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  "incomparable objects" % e, RuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py:1254: RuntimeWarning: unorderable types: int() > str(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  "incomparable objects" % e, RuntimeWarning)
Out[17]:
        0   1   2   3
china NaN NaN NaN NaN
kids  NaN NaN NaN NaN
music NaN NaN NaN NaN
yahoo NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

The NaNs do not go away even if I give index and column names to `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `x` and `blog_dat` have the same `index`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

blog_dat = pd.read_table("data", sep='\s+')
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4*4).reshape((4, 4)),
                 index=blog_dat.index)

pd.expanding_corr(blog_dat.iloc[:, :4], x, pairwise=True)[-1, :, :]
```

yields

```
              0         1         2         3
china  0.684896  0.260795 -0.990586  0.281298
kids   0.077209 -0.871448  0.702822  0.241313
music -0.203808  0.071436  0.581267 -0.783753
yahoo -0.630744  0.373339 -0.060623  0.258728
```

It's not enough to give `x` any index names; they must match the index of `blog_dat`.

Comment: Cool, actually only the index needs to be synced with blog_dat. But why even this is necessary is beyond me.

Comment: Many operations in Pandas align on the index. The correlation of data points from two Series is not matched by integer index location (as would be done by NumPy). Instead the data points are aligned by index. If the indexes don't match then the data points totally miss each other and the correlation is unknown, hence NaN is returned.